# Count Rows using Multiple Select Statements

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, count

Purpose is to count Rows from multiple ( 9 in total ) SELECT statements and display the row count in an application on a PHP page. Using Oracle 11g db

Dont care about selecting any content right here - just need the rowcount.

I haven't found a great way to count rows with Oracle and using Select statements.

What is the best way to count rows with Multiple Selects and Oracle and then display on PHP page ??

Please provide examples

This is what I have, but do this 9 times

```
$query  = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT ID"
. " FROM TABLE A"
. " WHERE (FieldX = 'N' AND FieldY = 'Y' AND FieldZ = 'Y')");

oci_execute($query) or die(oci_error($query));
oci_fetch_all($query, $array);
unset($array);
$numberofrows1 = oci_num_rows($query);
```

How can I make this more efficient ??

I try to use a field that is already indexed or a PK in the SELECT...

Comment: why wouldn't you just select count(...)?  Looks like you're selecting the data and then counting the rows returned, which isn't necessary if you just want a count

Comment: You'd certainly want to use an aggregate function (e.g. `count(*)`) rather than fetching the data and counting.  Are all your queries against the same table just with different criteria?  If so, you can do a single query that returns 1 row with 9 different columns each with a different count by doing a `sum( case when x = 'N' and y = 'Y' and z = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end)` and repeating for each set of criteria.

Comment: Justin - all queries from same table - just different WHERE conditions... yes a case statement will help - i will rewrite

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$query  = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT COUNT( * ) the_count"
. " FROM TABLE a"
. " WHERE FieldX = 'N'"
. " AND FieldY   = 'Y'"
. " AND FieldZ   = 'Y'");

oci_execute($query) or die(oci_error($query));
oci_fetch_all($query, $array);
```

Will return one row with one column named THE_COUNT containing the count of rows in table A matching the specified criteria.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for all the possible combinations of FieldX, Y and Z you can use this:

```
select pvt.*
  from (select FieldX, FieldY, FieldZ from a)
  PIVOT ( count(*) cnt
    FOR ( FieldX, FieldY, FieldZ)
     IN ( ('N', 'N', 'N') as N_N_N
        , ('N', 'N', 'Y') as N_N_Y
        , ('N', 'Y', 'N') as N_Y_N
        , ('N', 'Y', 'Y') as N_Y_Y
        , ('Y', 'N', 'N') as Y_N_N
        , ('Y', 'N', 'Y') as Y_N_Y
        , ('Y', 'Y', 'N') as Y_Y_N
        , ('Y', 'Y', 'Y') as Y_Y_Y )
        ) pvt
```

You may want to rename the columns a bit, but it'll do the trick returning one row with columns corresponding to a count of each of the possible combinations of FieldX, FieldY, and FieldZ.

If you include additional columns in the subselect you will get counts grouped by those additional columns.

Comment: This assumes that 'N' and 'Y' are the only valid values for those three fields.

Comment: You can add a total_count by changing `from (select FieldX, FieldY, FieldZ from a)` to `from (select count(*) over () total_cnt, FieldX, FieldY, FieldZ from a)` or by changing the select list to `select pvt.*, N_N_N_CNT+N_N_Y_CNT+...Y_Y_Y_CNT TOTAL_CNT`